# What are the health effects of drinking 1 beer a day?

Tags: alcohol, health-education, lasting-effects-duration

What are the health effects of drinking 1 beer a day? How bad would this be for my body and would areas of my health and life would this affect? Long term as well as short term.

Comment: Do you mean drinking one bear everyday or only a day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drinking one bear is actually not bad. It is called [moderate drinking](http://www.livestrong.com/article/509506-bad-effects-of-beer/) and in a nutshell, it is defined as consuming one drink a day for women and two for men. However, if you don’t drink now, you should not start drinking for health.  A healthy lifestyle, including good nutrition and exercise, offers more benefits than moderate drinking. Another important point is that if, as a man, you choose to have two beers a day, it does not mean it’s okay to guzzle one after the other. Drinking just two beers -- or any alcoholic drink -- in one hour impairs judgment and doubles your chances of having a traffic or household accident.

There are several [long and short-term effects](http://www.drugfreeworld.org/drugfacts/alcohol/short-term-long-term-effects.html) of alcoholic consumption but they are determined by the number of drinks taken per day.